# Is initializing a new RecyclerView Adapter an asynchronous call?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-adapter

My question is, is the initialization of a new `RecyclerView` adapter an asynchronous call?

I have an adapter that I am creating:

```
mRecyclerAdapter = new TestAdapter(mContext, mListImages);
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecycler.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
```

After initializing it, I can call `.add()` directly after these methods without calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()` and they would still be added to my adapter, and displayed.

```
mRecyclerAdapter = new TestAdapter(mContext, mListImages);
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecycler.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);

mListImages.add( . . .);
mListImages.add( . . .);
mListImages.add( . . .);
```

Are `RecyclerView` adapters automatically initialized on a background thread?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class SelectBucketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectBucketAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "SelectBucketAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mBucketList;

    public SelectBucketAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mBucketList,
                               ) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mBucketList = mBucketList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vh_selectbucketmenu_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ... binding views
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBucketList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.vh_selectbucketmenu_name)
        TextView vhBucketName;


        int mPosition;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are `RecyclerView` adapters automatically initialized on a background thread?

No, they are not.

> Is the initialization of a new `RecyclerView` adapter an asynchronous call?

No, it is not.

The layout creation and attachment to window ***is*** async.

### What this means?

Assume we have following code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  ...

  val adapter = MyAdapter()
  recyclerView.adapter = adapter

  adapter.list.add("1")
}
```

In this case we will see the "1" being displayed on the screen, because at the point when `adapter.list.add("1")` was executed `RecyclerView` hasn't yet passed through its `measure-layout-draw` cycle.

Now let's consider following code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  ...

  val adapter = MyAdapter()
  recyclerView.adapter = adapter

  Handler().postDelayed({ adapter.list.add("AAA") }, 2000)
}
```

In this case `adapter.list.add("AAA")` will be executed in roughly 2 seconds. As long as `RecyclerView` will already be laid out by that time, then mutating the adapter dataset won't make the `RecyclerView` show the item, because `RecyclerView` doesn't know if dataset has suffered a change.

Let's consider following case:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  ...

  val adapter = MyAdapter()
  recyclerView.adapter = adapter

  recyclerView.doOnPreDraw { adapter.list.add("preDraw") }
  recyclerView.doOnLayout { adapter.list.add("layout") }
  adapter.list.add("onCreate")
}
```

In this case still only *"onCreate"* will be displayed on screen.

To sum up: as soon as `RecyclerView` has passed its measure step (i.e. [`View#onMeasure`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onMeasure(int,%20int))) then mutating adapter won't be reflected unless adapter explicitly notifies `RecyclerView.`

Answer (score 1):

The term 'intiializing' is quite ambiguous. At what point do you consider the adapter 'intiialized'?. To me, an `Adapter` can be intiialized with 0 items. So you can't really measure whether the `Adapter` has been intiialized by looking at the contents of the `RecyclerView`.

Secondly, you're asking if 'intiializing is an asynchronous call'. The 'initialization' of a `RecyclerView Adapter` is a whole bunch of calls. What you've observed is that the result of these calls is not always immediately visible - which tells you that at least some of what is happening behind the scenes is asynchronous.

I think what you're trying to ask is 'at what point in the lifecycle of a RecyclerView are you required to notify the Adapter of changes'. And it sounds like the answer is 'once the `RecyclerView` has reached `onMeasure()` (based on @azizbekian's answer).

If you want to add items to the Adapter without having to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, then I would suggest adding them before calling `RecyclerView.setAdapter()`. Once you've set the `Adapter`, any further changes you make to the Adapter's dataset should be followed with a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call (or preferably, one of the more specific `notifyX()` calls).